# Generating wordpress posts based on wysiwyg html

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, content-management-system, wysiwyg

I have a large number of posts from an old wysiwyg CMS. Each post is basically stored in a single cell as html, it has paragraphs of text, img tags with paths to images etc.

I would like to generate new posts in a wordpress instance based on these chunks of html with some kind of script. I need to generate custom fields based on html table rows, upload new images to wordpress based on the paths to images etc.

This is a messy job.

It's probably hard for anyone to provide a solution for how to do this! But with this little background info, perhaps someone has done anything similar and can tell me about how that worked. Or maybe there is a tool for something like this.

Comment: Honestly it sounds like you're going to need to hire out a developer for this, it's far too broad to be answered here on StackOverflow. The most likely gist would be that you'll need to loop through each of the old posts, use [PHP's `DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to extract the content, title, meta fields, etc, and then use [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) to insert the new post.

Comment: This might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233344/convert-a-static-website-to-a-wordpress-theme-and-import-all-existing-content. But as Xhynk says, there are parts of your question that will require some coding (eg. importing table rows as custom fields).

Comment: Well I am a developer so that's not a problem, I'm just not very familiar with the internals of wordpress. Thanks a lot for the links, will check them out!